# How do I load an image from a DB inside a JSF page using managed beans?

Tags: image, jsf, load

I have a database with some images. Could anyone explain me how I could load an image in a JSF page?

I already have a managed bean that converts an Image object into a streamcontent. This streamcontent is called from the page in a tag `<h:graphicImage>`, but when I check the source code of the page, there's no `src` where the image could be loaded.

Answer (score 12):

The JSF `<h:graphicImage>` get rendered as a HTML `<img>` element. Its `src` attribute should point to an URL, not to the binary contents. So you should store the URL (or at least some identifier as request parameter or pathinfo) in the JSF bean and create a separate servlet to stream the image from the DB to the HTTP response.

Use this in your JSF page:

```
<h:graphicImage value="images/#{bean.imageId}">
```

Assuming that `bean.getImageId()` returns `123`, this get rendered in HTML as:

```
<img src="images/123">
```

Create a `Servlet` class which is mapped in `web.xml` on an `url-pattern` of `/images/*` and implement its `doGet()` method as follows.:

```
Long imageId = Long.valueOf(request.getPathInfo().substring(1)); // 123 (PS: don't forget to handle any exceptions).
Image image = imageDAO.find(imageId); // Get Image from DB.
// Image class is just a Javabean with the following properties:
// private String filename;
// private Long length;
// private InputStream content;

response.setHeader("Content-Type", getServletContext().getMimeType(image.getFilename()));
response.setHeader("Content-Length", image.getLength());
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + image.getFilename() + "\"");

BufferedInputStream input = null;
BufferedOutputStream output = null;

try {
    input = new BufferedInputStream(image.getContent());
    output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
    int length;
    while ((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
} finally {
    if (output != null) try { output.close(); } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {}
    if (input != null) try { input.close(); } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {}
}
```

In the `ImageDAO#find()` you can use [`ResultSet#getBinaryStream()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getBinaryStream%28java.lang.String%29) to the image as an `InputStream` from the database.

An extended example can be found in [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/04/imageservlet.html#ImageServletServingFromDatabase).

Comment: The Image Entity you refer to in above code should also contain 'height' & 'width' attributes no?

Comment: @thejartender: it's free to your choice :) It's however only useless in this context. You'd rather use it in the view side (JSP/Facelets/etc) while printing the necessary `<img>` elements.

Comment: For anyone stumbling over this: I'd stress the importance of NOT using the plain id to fetch the image unless you to want it totally easy to iterate (and download) all images from your database. Instead, use the hashed combination of id and filename as suggested in the article BalusC posted.