# Java Server Faces Loading images from array

Tags: java, jsf-2, javabeans

I have a class ImageBean and I want to use it to load images from an array. I have preloaded the array with images (9 in total) and want to display one image consecutively every time I refresh the browser. The images are named '1.jpg, 2.jpg' etc
(i.e image '1' -hit refresh, image '2' hit refresh, ... image '9'). Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

@ManagedBean(name="ImageBean")
@SessionScoped
public class ImageBean implements Serializable 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    ArrayList<Image> myArr = new ArrayList<Image>();
    BufferedImage img = null;

    public ImageBean()
    {
        for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            try 
            {
                img = ImageIO.read(new File(i + ".jpg"));
            } 
            catch (IOException ex) {}

            myArr.add(img);
        }
    }

    public BufferedImage getImage(int i) 
    {
        return (BufferedImage) myArr.get(i);
    }
}
```

Edit 1

I have edited the code slightly so I use an array of BufferedImage instead of an ArrayList. Now I don't get an error, but the image is not displayed in the browser.

```
public class ImageBean implements Serializable 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    BufferedImage[] myArr = new BufferedImage[9];

    public ImageBean()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            try 
            {
                myArr[i] = (ImageIO.read(new File(i+1 + ".jpg")));
            } 
            catch (IOException ex) {}
        }
    }

    public BufferedImage getImage(int i) 
    {
        return (BufferedImage) myArr[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Crossposted to https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2362283

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to add a variable to hold the current image and just get the next image... (just keep in mind to reset for the last image)

```
@SessionScoped
public class ImageBean implements Serializable 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    ArrayList<Image> myArr = new ArrayList<Image>();
    BufferedImage img = null;

    private int currImgId = 1;

    public ImageBean()
    {
        for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            try 
            {
                img = ImageIO.read(new File(i + ".jpg"));
            } 
            catch (IOException ex) {}

            myArr.add(img);
        }
    }

  public BufferedImage getImage() 
  {
    // Reset logic would go here...probably best with array.size...
    return (BufferedImage) myArr.get(currImgId++);
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think the problem lies with my Java Server Page. `code` <h:graphicImage value="#{ImageBean.getImage(0)}" alt="The image could not be found."/> `code` is what I have in my JSP class, im sure it is wrong.

Comment: Could possibly create an ArrayOutOfBonds error, as this would keep rising up past 8.

Comment: Any suggestions on the JSP class?

Comment: Well your problem is that h:graphicImage  is intended for URL not binary data so either you create a Servlet to get the images (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848964/how-do-i-load-an-image-from-a-db-inside-a-jsf-page-using-managed-beans) for a reference, or use something like richFaces (<a4j:mediaOutput> look [here](http://richfaces-showcase.appspot.com/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=mediaOutput&skin=blueSky) ) or prime Faces, etc.

Comment: @omegaFlame, one more thing please do listen to Legend, you have to replace the getImage code with something that checks ArraySize before doing the currImgId++.. 
And one more thing (as I was told recently.. ) since you are new here don't forget to mark the answer as accepted (actually the answer that helped the most.. if any..;-) )..

Comment: @FMQ thanks for all your replies and the links. I actually solved this by using a different method last night.

Answer (score 0):

```
public ImageBean()
    {
        for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            try 
            {
                myArr.add(ImageIO.read(new File(i + ".jpg")));
            } 
            catch (IOException ex) {}
        }
    }
```

originally if it failed it would keep adding the previous image. This may have made it 'freeze' as it would really be going through the images, but actually just be displaying the same.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But now I get java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0 thrown in the browser. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: I have a JSF page with the line <h:graphicImage value="#{ImageBean.getImage(0)}" alt="The image could not be found."/> within the body I believe this is the cause.